# How to select values from two tables that are not contained in the map table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery

Lets say I have the following tables:

- Customers
- Products
- CustomerProducts

Is there a way I can do a select from the Customers and Products tables, where the values are NOT in the map table?  Basically I need a matched list of Customers and Products they do NOT own.

Another twist: I need to pair one customer per product.  So If 5 customers do not have Product A, only the first customer in the query should have Product A.  So the results would look something like this:

(Assume that all customers own product B, And more than one customer owns products A, C, and D)

1. Customer 1, Product A
2. Customer 2, Product C
3. Customer 3, Product D

Final twist:  I need to run this query as part of an UPDATE statement in SQL Sever.  So I need to take the value from the first row:

Customer 1, Product A

and update the Customer record to something like

```
UPDATE Customers
SET Customers.UnownedProduct = ProductA
WHERE Customers.CustomerID = Customer1ID
```

But it would be nice if I could do this whole process, in one SQL statement.  So I run the query once, and it updates 1 customer with a product they do not own.
Hope that's not too confusing for you!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if you have two customers and only one prdouct, that both of them do not own?

Comment: Then the query should return only 1 record, with the first customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH q AS
        (
        SELECT  c.*, p.id AS Unowned,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY c.id) AS rn
        FROM    Customers c
        CROSS JOIN
                Products p
        LEFT JOIN 
                CustomerProducts cp
        ON      cp.customer = c.id
                AND cp.product = p.id
        WHERE   cp.customer IS NULL
        )
UPDATE  q
SET     UnownedProduct = Unowned
WHERE   rn = 1
```

`UPDATE` statement will update the *first* customer who doesn't own a certain product.

If you want to select the list, you'll need:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  c.*, p.id AS Unowned,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY c.id) AS rn
        FROM    Customers c
        CROSS JOIN
                Products p
        LEFT JOIN 
                CustomerProducts cp
        ON      cp.customer = c.id
                AND cp.product = p.id
        WHERE   cp.customer IS NULL
    ) cpo
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the OP's Another and Final twist?!

Comment: This takes both into account :)

Answer (score 0):

If you update only one customer at once, you might need to remember which products have been assigned automatically (in CustomerProducts) or have a counter how often a product has been assigned automatically (in Products)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in oracle (hope it works for you too)

```
UPDATE customers c
   SET unownedProduct =
       ( SELECT MIN( productid )
           FROM products
          WHERE productid NOT IN (
              SELECT unownedProduct
                FROM customers
               WHERE unownedProduct IS NOT NULL )
            AND productid NOT IN (
              SELECT productid
                FROM customerProducts cp
               WHERE cp.customerId = c.customerid )
       )
 WHERE customerId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What if the customer doesn't own more than one product? and how are you going to maintain this field as the data changes? I thinkyou really need to do some more thinking about your data structure as it doesn't make sense to store this information in the customer table.